# Different output fetching json with and without arrow function on reactjs

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, parsing, fetch

Why I am getting different responses when fetching json? When I use arrow function it works and when not it doesn't work.

```
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    data: [],
  };
  this.url = 'https://fcctop100.herokuapp.com/api/fccusers/top/recent';
}
```

Fetch with arrow function:

```
fetch(url)
  .then((response) => {
    return response.json()
  }).then((json) => {
    this.setState({data: json});
    console.log('parsed json', json)
  }).catch((ex) => {
    console.log('parsing failed', ex)
  });
```

Returns on console:

```
parsed json Array [ Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, 90 more… ]
```

And when I don't use arrow function the output is different:

```
fetch(url)
  .then((response) => {
    return response.json()
  }).then(function(json) {
    this.setState({data: json});
    console.log('parsed json', json)
  }).catch((ex) => {
    console.log('parsing failed', ex)
  });
```

Returns this:

```
parsing failed TypeError: this is undefined Stack trace:
listCampers/<@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:18177:17
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`arrow function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_binding_of_this) does not have own **`this`** and refers to parent *scope*(*in this case it is React component*). If you use `function` you have to set **`this`** by you own, because in this case **`this`** refers to global scope(*in browser it is `window`*) or if you use `strict mode` **`this`** will be `undefined`

```
.then(function(json) {
  this.setState({data: json});
  console.log('parsed json', json)
}.bind(this))
 ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes because in the second case

```
fetch(url)
  .then((response) => {
    return response.json()
  }).then(function(json) {
    this.setState({data: json});    ///The error is given here 
    console.log('parsed json', json)
  }).catch((ex) => {
    console.log('parsing failed', ex)
  });
```

you are using `this.setState` but the success callback is not bound to the React Component context and hence `this` will refer to the context of `.then` function itself and hence `setState` will not be available

While in the first case, `this` inside arrow functions  refer to the parents context which in your case would be the React Component context
where setState was available and hence you get a proper output